# SQL: Select distinct while ignoring only one column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table like this. [input table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMiU0.png)

```sql
name  age  amount  xyz
dip    3     12    22a
dip    3     12    23a
oli    4     34    23b
mou    5     56    23b
mou    5     56    23a
maa    7     68    24c
```

I want to find distinct rows but want to ignore the column 'xyz' while finding distinct.
The output should look like this. [output table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qe8KC.png)

```sql
  name  age  amount  xyz
dip    3      12     22a
oli    4      34     23b
mou    5      56     23b
maa    7      68     24c
```

`SELECT DISTINCT * EXCEPT (xyz) FROM table`

but it didn't work.

Comment: For the records where name=mou, what are the rules about which value if xyz to select? Why has your result got 23b and not 23a?

Comment: As in MYSQL there is not other but to manually specify column that you want.. there is no shortcut to exclude column.. so in your case you will have to specify all 3 columns name instead of wildcards..

Comment: @NickW for name=mou keep the first ie. xyz =  23b

Comment: @paul, since rows in a table doesn't have order property by default, you should specify the ordering column like `timestamp` to keep the first.

Answer (score 1):

few more options

```
select any_value(t).*
from your_table t
group by t.name, t.age, t.amount
```

with output

[image]

if you need MIN or MAX  - you can use below

```
select any_value(t having min xyz).*
from your_table t
group by t.name, t.age, t.amount
```

or

```
select * from your_table
qualify xyz = min(xyz) over(partition by name, age, amount)
```

with output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use group by, try the below and see if it works:

```
SELECT name, age, amount, MIN(xyz) AS xyz
FROM table
GROUP BY name, age, amount
```

Comment: Since BigQuery allows repeated fields, you may want to consider using array_agg. This way no data is lost.